# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null using Tabbis

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tabbis</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/dist/style-default.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
          /* Reset */
          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:600&display=swap');
    
          * {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: quicksand;
          }
    
          body {
            padding: 4rem;
            background: #eee;
    
            @media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
              padding: 0;
            }
          }

          .gallerycontainer{
            position: relative;
    /*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
          }
    
          .thumbnail img{
            border: 1px solid white;
            margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
          }
    
          .thumbnail:hover{
            background-color: blue;
          }
    
          .thumbnail:hover img{
            border: 1px solid blue;
          }
    
          .thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
            position: fixed;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 5px;
            right: 0;
            /*border: 1px dashed gray;*/
            visibility: hidden;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
          }
    
          .thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
            border-width: 0;
            padding: 2px;
          }
    
          .thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
            visibility: visible;
            top: 50px;
            left: 500px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
            z-index: 50;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div data-tabs>
          <button>INDEX</button>
          <button>NORTH</button>
          <button>SOUTH</button>
          <button>EXTENSION</button>
        </div>
    
        <div data-panes>
    <!-- Index Tab  -->
          <div>INDEX</div>
    <!-- North Tab  -->
          <div>
    <!-- NE Tabs  -->
            <div data-tabs>
              <button>EAST</button>
              <button>WEST</button>
              <button>TN</button>
            </div>
            <div data-panes>
              <div>
                <div data-tabs>
                  <button>DNE</button>
                  <button>HNE</button>
                  <button>KNE</button>
                  <button>ENE</button>
                  <button>WNE</button>
                  <button>ANE</button>
                  <button>QNE</button>
                  <button>BNE</button>
                  <button>SNE</button>
                  <button>FNE</button>
                  <button>XNE</button>
                  <button>NNE</button>
                  <button>CNE</button>
                  <button>ACN</button>
                  <button>YNE</button>
                  <button>PB3</button>
                </div>
              <div data-panes>
                <button>DNE JPGs HERE</button>
                <button>HNE</button>
                <button>KNE</button>
                <button>ENE</button>
                <button>WNE</button>
                <button>ANE</button>
                <button>QNE</button>
                <button>BNE</button>
                <button>SNE</button>
                <button>FNE</button>
                <button>XNE</button>
                <button>NNE</button>
                <button>CNE</button>
                <button>ACN</button>
                <button>YNE</button>
                <button>PB3</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    <!-- NW Tabs  -->
            <div>
              <div data-tabs>
                <button>DNW</button>
                <button>HNW</button>
                <button>KNW</button>
                <button>ENW</button>
                <button>WNW</button>
                <button>ANW</button>
                <button>QNW</button>
                <button>BNW</button>
                <button>SNW</button>
                <button>FNW</button>
                <button>XNW</button>
                <button>NNW</button>
                <button>CNW</button>
                <button>ACN</button>
                <button>YNW</button>
                <button>PB1</button>
              </div>
              <div data-panes>
                <button>DNW JPGs HERE</button>
                <button>HNW</button>
                <button>KNW</button>
                <button>ENW</button>
                <button>WNW</button>
                <button>ANW</button>
                <button>QNW</button>
                <button>BNW</button>
                <button>SNW</button>
                <button>FNW</button>
                <button>XNW</button>
                <button>NNW</button>
                <button>CNW</button>
                <button>ACN</button>
                <button>YNW</button>
                <button>PB1</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    <!-- TN Tab  -->
              <div>Pane TN</div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
    
    
    <!-- SOUTH  -->
          <div>
            <div data-tabs>
              <button>EAST</button>
              <button>WEST</button>
              <button>TS</button>
            </div>
            <div data-panes>
    
    <!-- SE Tabs  -->
            <div>
              <div data-tabs>
                <button>DSE</button>
                <button>HSE</button>
                <button>KSE</button>
                <button>ESE</button>
                <button>WSE</button>
                <button>ASE</button>
                <button>QSE</button>
                <button>BSE</button>
                <button>SSE</button>
                <button>FSE</button>
                <button>XSE</button>
                <button>NSE</button>
                <button>CSE</button>
                <button>ACS</button>
                <button>YSE</button>
                <button>PB4</button>
              </div>
              <div data-panes>
                <button>DSE JPGs HERE</button>
                <button>HSE</button>
                <button>KSE</button>
                <button>ESE</button>
                <button>WSE</button>
                <button>ASE</button>
                <button>QSE</button>
                <button>BSE</button>
                <button>SSE</button>
                <button>FSE</button>
                <button>XSE</button>
                <button>NSE</button>
                <button>CSE</button>
                <button>ACS</button>
                <button>YSE</button>
                <button>PB4</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    <!-- SW Tabs  -->
            <div>
              <div data-tabs>
                <button>DSW</button>
                <button>HSW</button>
                <button>KSW</button>
                <button>ESW</button>
                <button>WSW</button>
                <button>ASW</button>
                <button>QSW</button>
                <button>BSW</button>
                <button>SSW</button>
                <button>FSW</button>
                <button>XSW</button>
                <button>NSW</button>
                <button>CSW</button>
                <button>ASN</button>
                <button>YSW</button>
                <button>PB2</button>
              </div>
              <div data-panes>
                <button>DSW</button>
                <button>HSW</button>
                <button>KSW</button>
                <button>ESW</button>
                <button>WSW</button>
                <button>ASW</button>
                <button>QSW</button>
                <button>BSW</button>
                <button>SSW</button>
                <button>FSW</button>
                <button>XSW</button>
                <button>NSW</button>
                <button>CSW</button>
                <button>ASN</button>
                <button>YSW</button>
                <button>PB2</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    <!-- TS Tab  -->
            <div>Pane TS</div>
          </div>
        </div>



    <!-- EXTENSION  -->
        <div>
          <div data-tabs>
            <button>EAST</button>
            <button>WEST</button>
            <button>TSX</button>
          </div>
          <div data-panes>
    
    <!-- SEX Tabs  -->
            <div>
              <div data-tabs>
                <button onclick="onClick()">DSEX</button>
                <button onclick="onClick()">HSEX</button>
                <button onclick="onClick()">KSEX</button>
                <button>ESEX</button>
                <button>WSEX</button>
                <button>ASEX</button>
                <button>QSEX</button>
                <button>BSEX</button>
                <button>SSEX</button>
                <button>FSEX</button>
                <button>XSEX</button>
                <button>NSEX</button>
                <button>CSEX</button>
                <button>ACSX</button>
                <button>YSEX</button>
                <button>PB8</button>
              </div>
              <div data-panes>
                <button>
                  <div id="dsex">DSEX</div>
                </button>
                <button>
                  <div id="hsex>">HSEX</div>
                </button>
                <button>
                  <div id="ksex>"></div>
                </button>
                <button>ESEX</button>
                <button>WSEX</button>
                <button>ASEX</button>
                <button>QSEX</button>
                <button>BSEX</button>
                <button>SSEX</button>
                <button>FSEX</button>
                <button>XSEX</button>
                <button>NSEX</button>
                <button>CSEX</button>
                <button>ACSX</button>
                <button>YSEX</button>
                <button>PB8</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          <!-- SWX Tabs  -->
            <div>
              <div data-tabs>
                <button>DSWX</button>
                <button>HSWX</button>
                <button>KSWX</button>
                <button>ESWX</button>
                <button>WSWX</button>
                <button>ASWX</button>
                <button>QSWX</button>
                <button>BSWX</button>
                <button>SSWX</button>
                <button>FSWX</button>
                <button>XSWX</button>
                <button>NSWX</button>
                <button>CSWX</button>
                <button>ASNX</button>
                <button>YSWX</button>
                <button>PB6</button>
              </div>
              <div data-panes>
                <button>DSWX</button>
                <button>HSWX</button>
                <button>KSWX</button>
                <button>ESWX</button>
                <button>WSWX</button>
                <button>ASWX</button>
                <button>QSWX</button>
                <button>BSWX</button>
                <button>SSWX</button>
                <button>FSWX</button>
                <button>XSWX</button>
                <button>NSWX</button>
                <button>CSWX</button>
                <button>ASNX</button>
                <button>YSWX</button>
                <button>PB6</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          <!-- TSX Tab  -->
            <div>Pane TS</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
      </div>
    
        <script src="../assets/js/dist/tabbis.es6.js"></script>
        <script>
          tabbis({
            memory: true
          });
        </script>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
    var elementaries = '../assets/elementaries/';
    var elemLoc = [];
    var dsex = [
      "this.jpg",
      "that.jpg"
    ];
    var hsex = [
      "this.jpg",
      "that.jpg"
    ];
    
    
    // ON click of quadrant (DSEX...) do this
    function onClick() {
    
      let id = event.srcElement.id; // returns the id of the button (tab 8-0)
      let quadrant = document.getElementById(`${id}`).innerHTML.toLowerCase(); // returns the value of the button ie DSEX
      getElemLoc(quadrant); // calls function to make an array of elementaries based on quadrant
      loadElementaries(quadrant); // loads elementaries under proper tab
    }
    
    // Function makes an array of elementaries based on quadrant
    var getElemLoc = (q) => {
      elemLoc = [];
      let elem = window[q];
      elem.forEach(function (img) {
        let loc = `${elementaries}${q}/${img}`;
        elemLoc.push(loc);
      })
    };
    
    // Loads elementaries to proper div based on quadrant.
    var loadElementaries = (quad) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < elemLoc.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(`${quad}`).innerHTML = document.getElementById(`${quad}`).innerHTML + `<a class="thumbnail" href="${elemLoc[i]}"><img src="${elemLoc[i]}" width="350px" height="250px" border="0" /><span><img src="${elemLoc[i]}" width="900" height="700" /><br /></span></a> <br />`;
      }
    };
```

When going to the tab Extension/East/DSEX my innerhtml code works perfectly, but if I try the hsex tab the inner html in loadElementaries fails.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on.  Maybe the way the DOM is loading between tabs?
`` document.getElementById(`${quad}`).innerHTML `` works for dsex tab but not hsex...

I'm at work so I'm limited to using client side JS/HTML/CSS so nodejs isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: ```(`${id}`)``` is a really long winded way of writing `(id)`

Comment: haha good point, I'm kind of a noob I'm not sure why I did that